# Derivation (¬¬A → A) → (¬¬B → B) → ¬¬(A ∧ B) → A ∧ B.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I am struggling trying to make a derivation of this principle of indirect proof.
Starting with the needed assumptions:

u: ¬¬A → A 
 v:¬¬B → B 
 w: ¬¬(A ∧ B)

I thought that in order to prove A ∧ B I will need to prove A and B separately first and then just use the introduction rule for ∧. But I did not find a proper way. Can anyone help me please with that? Is the choice of assupmtions unique? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean with the long string of symbols? Do you mean that there are two premises and one conclusion:  $¬¬(A ∧ B) → (A ∧ B)$?

Comment: If so the strategy is clear: assume both $\lnot A$ and $\lnot B$ and derive contradictions, in order to conclude with $\lnot \lnot A$ and $\lnot \lnot B$. Then use the premises to derive both $A$ and $B$.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: This question is really unclear. What statement do you need to prove,  from what, and how?  What are these 'u', 'v', and 'w'? Is there some rule or principle that you are using that refer to 'u', 'v', and 'w'? Indeed, can you provide us with some details about the system with which you are supposed to work? There are many different systems and principles in logic, so we really need some more context to be able to help you out.

Comment: IMO, what you are aiming to prove is: $(¬¬A → A), (¬¬B → B),¬¬(A ∧ B) \vdash A ∧ B$. If so, it is a "standard" ND derivation: please confirm.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA yes the first two (¬¬A→A),(¬¬B→B) are premises and then comes the conclusions. I found this in the book "Proofs and Computations" and it is written exactly in that way!

Comment: Thanks; see page 1: it is a shorthand for the version with parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

We have to write the derivation:

$(¬¬A→A),(¬¬B→B),¬¬(A∧B) ⊢ A∧B$.

The conclusion will follow with three applications of $(\to \text {Intro})$ (called $\to^+$: page 10).

1. $(¬¬A→A)$ --- premise
2. $(¬¬B→B)$ --- premise
3. $¬¬(A∧B)$ --- premise
4. $¬A$ --- assumption [a]
5. $A∧B$ --- assumption [b]
6. $A$ --- from 5) by $(\land \text {Elim})$ [$\land^-$]
7. $\bot$ --- contradiction: from 4) and 6) [by def of negation, page 7 and $\to^-$]
8. $\lnot (A∧B)$ --- from 5) and 7) by $\to^+$ and def, discharging assumption [b]
9. $\bot$ --- contradiction: from 3) and 8)
10. $\lnot \lnot A$ --- from 4) and 9) by $\to^+$ and def, discharging assumption [a]

> 11. $A$ --- from 1) and 10) by $\to^-$.

Now repeat the same derivation with assumption $\lnot B$ in line 4) and you will have $B$.

Then:

> $A \land B$ --- from the above by $\land^+$.